# Creating arrays from inputs?

Tags: php

I wish to store an arbitrary number of answers to a question on a form in a single field (json).

So the inputs may be something like:

Your Jobs:

- job title
- start date
- end date

I know I can call the input `<input name="job_title[]">` and these would all be listed as an array under `job_title`. But is there anyway to have all three inputs listed under a keyed array just by naming the inputs in a specific way, something like:

```
[jobs => [['job_title' => 'xyz', 'start_date` => 'xyz', 'send_date` => 'xyz'], ....]
```

Or would I need to build this manually in php with loops?

Comment: you mean directly from `$_POST`?

Comment: How do your pass your data? Ajax or also with a php file?

Comment: yes directly from post

Comment: Your are looking for collections in php, you may want to look some librarie that handle this very well

Comment: i believe you simply can use `<input name="jobs[job_title]">` and `<input name="jobs[start_date]">` and `<input name="jobs[send_date]">` in the HTML code i believe that should give the array you are looking for.. it might require a extra `[]` at the end like `<input name="jobs[job_title][]">` test it a little bit.

Comment: You probably want something like `<input name="jobs[0]['title']">`, etc.

Comment: @jeroen the `[0]` is correct but you don't have or i believe it's not even allowed in HTML array to use quotes of anny kind i could be wrong here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland It could be that the quotes are wrong, I haven't tested it. I hardly ever do this manually :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting a single subset group, you can specify the key to use in your input list

```
<input name="name" value="John Doe">
<input name="jobs[job_title]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[start_date]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[send_date]" value="xyz">
```

Results:

```
$_POST => [
    'name' => 'John Doe'
    'jobs' ['job_title' => 'xyz', 'start_date' => 'xyz', 'send_date' => 'xyz'],
     //...
];
```

If you want to accept more than one job, depending on how you would like your data to be associated, it is recommended to use an explicitly defined grouping index.

To associate the values sequentially, similarly to how you would receive from a database result set, you can use a simple incremental variable for your data set groups.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][job_title]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][start_date]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][send_date]" value="xyz">
<?php $i++; ?>
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][job_title]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][start_date]" value="xyz">
<input name="jobs[<?php echo $i; ?>][send_date]" value="xyz">
<?php $i++; ?>

...
```

Results: `$_POST['jobs'][$group][$field]`

```
$_POST => [
    'jobs' => [
         0 => ['job_title' => 'xyz', 'start_date' => 'xyz', 'send_date' => 'xyz'],
         1 => ['job_title' => 'xyz', 'start_date' => 'xyz', 'send_date' => 'xyz'],
         //...
    ],
];
```

> Excluding the input grouping value `$i`, 
>   like `name="jobs[][field]"` 
>   will result in PHP automatically incrementing
>   the `$_POST` array index of the jobs.
>
> It is the equivalent of using `$jobs[] = ['field' => 'value']`
>
> ```
> $_POST => [
>     'jobs' => [
>          0 => ['job_title' => 'xyz', ],
>          1 => ['start_date' => 'xyz'],
>          2 => ['send_date' => 'xyz']
>     ]
> ];
> ```

---

Alternatively you can use a database identifier column value when iterating over the results, which is beneficial when performing updates to existing records.

```
<?php 

 $results = [
    ['id' => 1, 'job_title' => 'abc', 'start_date' => 'abc', 'send_date' => 'abc'],
    ['id' => 2, 'job_title' => 'xyz', 'start_date' => 'xyz', 'send_date' => 'xyz'],
 ];

 foreach ($results as $row) { ?>
     <input name="jobs[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>][job_title]" value="<?php echo $row['job_title']; ?>">
     <input name="jobs[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>][start_date]" value="<?php echo $row['start_date']; ?>">
     <input name="jobs[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>][send_date]" value="<?php echo $row['send_date']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to create an array based on the Posted input value? Just use the foreach loop with the `$_POST` variable like

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { // for every post value
        $array[] = array( // we create a array based on the name and the value
            $key => $value
        );
    }
    var_dump($array); // dump the array
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="job title" value="xyz">
    <input type="text" name="start date" value="xyz">
    <input type="text" name="send date" value="xyz">
    <!-- any other input -->
    <button type="submit">sd</button>
</form>
```

The `var_dump($array)` will give you

```php
array(2) { ["job_title"]=> string(3) "xyz" ["start_date"]=> string(3) "xyz" } array(1) { ["send_date"]=> string(3) "xyz" }
```

To create JSON from the array just do

```
echo json_encode($array)
```

Comment: Your code https://3v4l.org/n2ncP results in only the last input field value `array(1) {
  ["send_date"]=>
  string(3) "xyz"
}` In this instance. You would need to use `$array[] =` to append to the array, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @fyrye thanks for figuring out the problem. Else it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: No problem, but I am confused as to why you would not just use `json_encode($_POST)`, since `$array` would result in having the same key and value pairs as `$_POST`.

Comment: @fyrye well, we don't know if the user is adding more fields to his POST request. The question is about the input and their values only. So that's why. Else you can do that too.

Comment: you down voted because you wrote name of text fields with space and on array you are showing them with underscore @window.document